# Initiate multiple processes within Tkinter GUI. (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, multiprocessing, pickle

I am developing an in-house app at work for image processing/computer vision using Tkinter. I'm used to hacking my way through some code to get something up and running quickly, and user-friendly is not within my realm of experience. The end-user will need to set some values manually before initiating the time-consuming part of the program.

The problem I am up against is this: due to the number of images being processed, the program takes a long time (~1 hr). I see significant speedup (around a third of the time) when splitting up the processing across 4 cores (FYI - no communication between processes is necessary); however, I get errors thrown at me when I try to start a new process from the Tkinter class.

Being thoroughly in over my head, I have long-succumbed to the seductive allure of the copy-paste succubi and now hardly understand anything that I am trying. I have found similar issues [here](http://www.rueckstiess.net/research/snippets/show/ca1d7d90) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972445/problem-with-pickle-and-tkinter), and implementing the changes suggested therein exchanged my errors for new ones. See all errors below.

Initial try:

```
import Tkinter
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool

class userApp(Tkinter.Frame):

    def multi_proc(self):
        arg_gen = ((n) for n in self.values)
        manager = Manager()
        self.ret = manager.dict()
        pool = Pool(4)
        jobs = pool.map_async(self.func2, arg_gen)
        self.ret = jobs.get()


    def func1(self):
        self.values = range(15)

    def func2(self,args):
        return("I'm #%d"%(args[0]))

    def _quit(self):
        self.quit()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(root,text="Set some values",command=self.func1)
        self.button2 = Tkinter.Button(root,text="Start processes",command=self.multi_proc)
        self.button3 = Tkinter.Button(root,text="Quit",command=self._quit)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3.pack()

   def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Select an option")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = userApp(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

This returns the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\...\TestScript.py", line 13, in multi_proc
    self.ret = jobs.get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Wrapping `func2()` outside of the Tk app and sending the arguments out to the wrapper results in a different `pickling` error:

```
class userApp(Tkinter.Frame):
    ...

    def multi_proc(self):
        arg_gen = ((n) for n in self.values)
        manager = Manager()
        self.ret = manager.dict()
        pool = Pool(4)
        jobs = pool.map_async(unwrap_self_f, zip([self]*len(self.values), arg_gen))
        self.ret = jobs.get()
    ...

def unwrap_self_f(arg, **kwarg):
    return userApp.func2(*arg, **kwarg)
```

Throws:

```
... same as before ...
UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <type 'tkapp'> objects
```

And finally (sorry for the long post), adding this to the class:

```
    def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        del state['view']
        return state
```

throws this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\...\TestScript.py", line 13, in multi_proc
    self.ret = jobs.get()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
KeyError: 'view'
```

I know future self is going to look back on current self and tell me I'm an idiot, but in the meantime, any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Tkinter isn't a thread safe module for python, so you may find that even if you do get the programming running without errors, it randomly fails to respond and completely crashes at random points throughout the program. Any Tkinter related calls that get made make sure they are made in the main thread with the exception of root.after(). I would suggest doing all your processing in separate threads, and then when using Tkinter call methods you want via the after method with a delay of 1, which will ensure no random crashes. This wont fix your current issues, but it will fix ones later.

Comment: Got it. I'll do a bit of research into [this](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm) and see what I can come up with. I'm thinking it may be easier at this point to rework the whole thing and do away with most of the gui. My end-user may just have to overcome his fear of command-line interfaces and do some typing.