# Python tkinter: error _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button2"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a homescreen for my python tkinter program and I am having a strange error with my toggle button.

I defined 2 functions: The first one called `self.do_on()` destroys the off button and places the on button. The second one called `self.do_off()` destroys the on button and places the off button.

The off button is placed by default.

The program successfully execute the `self.do_off()` function and turns the off button to the on one when the off button is pressed. But then when I press the one button that has been placed, it just destroys the on button and returns an error.

***Here's the program:***

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time

def isNumber():
    try:
        int(root.enteredTime)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def callback1(var, index, mode):
    root.enteredTime = str(root.entryTime.get()).replace(":", "")
    if isNumber() == False:
        print(root.changes)
        print(root.changes[-1])
        root.entryTime.delete(0,'end')
        root.entryTime.insert('end', root.changes[-1])
    else:
        if len(root.enteredTime) <= 2:
            root.entryTime.delete(0,'end')
            root.entryTime.insert('end', root.enteredTime)
            root.entryTime.insert('end', ':')

        if len(root.enteredTime) == 4:
            root.enteredTimeO = root.entryTime.get()

        if len(root.enteredTime) >= 4:
            root.focus()
            root.entryTime.delete(0,'end')
            root.entryTime.insert('end', root.enteredTimeO)
        root.adds = root.adds +1
        root.changes.append(str(root.entryTime.get()))

class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root, self).__init__()
        self.off = PhotoImage(file = "OFF.png")
        self.on = PhotoImage(file = "ON.png")
        
        self.title("Chess Clock")
        self.minsize(1539,800)
        #self.wm_iconbitmap(r"")
        self.windowBG = '#313131'
        self.state('zoomed')
        self.configure(bg=self.windowBG)
        self.adds = 0
        self.changes = []

        self.createHomeScreen()

    def do_off(self):
        self.onBtn.destroy()
        self.offBtn.place(x=900, y=390)

    def do_on(self):
        self.offBtn.destroy()
        self.onBtn.place(x=900, y=390)

    def createHomeScreen(self):
        self.bg2 = Label(self, width=185, height=45, bg='#252525')
        self.bg2.place(x=120, y=85)
        
        Label(self, text='Time per player:', bg='#252525', fg='#AAA4A6', font ="Gadugi 30 bold").place(x=170, y=140)
        
        Label(self, text='Extra Seconds:', bg='#252525', fg='#AAA4A6', font ="Gadugi 30 bold").place(x=170, y=240)
        Label(self, text='Extra Seconds are added every move.', bg='#252525', fg='#656565', font ="Gadugi 15").place(x=185, y=300)

        Label(self, text='Sound Notifications:', bg='#252525', fg='#AAA4A6', font ="Gadugi 30 bold").place(x=170, y=380)
        Label(self, text='A sound notification will be emitted when clock is switched from a player to another one, when there is 30 or 10 seconds left ', bg='#252525', fg='#656565', font ="Gadugi 15").place(x=185, y=475)
        Label(self, text='and also when the game is over.', bg='#252525', fg='#656565', font ="Gadugi 15").place(x=185, y=500)


        self.setTime = StringVar()
        self.entryTime = Entry(self, width=5, textvariable = self.setTime, font="Gadugi 30", background='#252525', fg='white', justify='center', insertbackground='white', borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.entryTime.place(x=1000, y=140)

        self.entryTime.focus()
        self.setTime.trace_add("write", callback1)

        self.onBtn = Button(self, image=self.on, bd=0, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, command=self.do_off)
        self.offBtn = Button(self, image=self.off, bd=0, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, command=self.do_on)
        self.offBtn.place(x=900, y=390)



root=root()
root.mainloop()
```

***Here's the error:***

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Users\Jean Paul\OneDrive\Programming\Programs\Prog 6 - Chess Clock\test.py", line 56, in do_off
    self.offBtn.place(x=900, y=390)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2448, in place_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button2"
```

***Here are the off and on buttons images:***

`ON.png`:

[image]

`OFF.png`:

[image]

***[Here's a video showing the problem.](https://vimeo.com/716056181)***

Comment: The `.destroy()` method does exactly what its name implies - you cannot reinstate the widget just by calling `.place()` again.  Use `.place_forget()` instead to merely hide the widgets rather than destroying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code posted in the question with in the comments suggested change to replace `.destroy()` with `.place_forget()` . This solves the described problem:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465414/python-tkinter-error-tkinter-tclerror-bad-window-path-name-button2

from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label, StringVar, Entry, Button
import time

def isNumber():
    try:
        int(root.enteredTime)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def callback1(var, index, mode):
    root.enteredTime = str(root.entryTime.get()).replace(":", "")
    if isNumber() == False:
        print(root.changes)
        print(root.changes[-1])
        root.entryTime.delete(0,'end')
        root.entryTime.insert('end', root.changes[-1])
    else:
        if len(root.enteredTime) <= 2:
            root.entryTime.delete(0,'end')
            root.entryTime.insert('end', root.enteredTime)
            root.entryTime.insert('end', ':')

        if len(root.enteredTime) == 4:
            root.enteredTimeO = root.entryTime.get()

        if len(root.enteredTime) >= 4:
            root.focus()
            root.entryTime.delete(0,'end')
            root.entryTime.insert('end', root.enteredTimeO)
        root.adds = root.adds +1
        root.changes.append(str(root.entryTime.get()))

class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root, self).__init__()
        self.off = PhotoImage(file = "OFF.png")
        self.on  = PhotoImage(file = "ON.png")
        
        self.title("Chess Clock")
        self.minsize(1725,800)
        # self.wm_iconbitmap(r"")
        self.windowBG = '#313131'
        # self.state('zoomed') # gives an error
        self.state('normal')
        self.configure(bg=self.windowBG)
        self.adds = 0
        self.changes = []

        self.createHomeScreen()

    def do_off(self):
        self.onBtn.place_forget()  # stop to show the placed button
        # self.onBtn.destroy() will make the button unavailable
        self.offBtn.place(x=900, y=390)

    def do_on(self):
        self.offBtn.place_forget() # stop to show the placed button
        self.onBtn.place(x=900, y=390)

    def createHomeScreen(self):
        self.bg2 = Label(self, width=185, height=45, bg='#252525')
        self.bg2.place(x=120, y=85)
        
        Label(self, text='Time per player:', 
            bg='#252525', fg='#AAA4A6', font ="Gadugi 30 bold" ).place(x=170, y=140)
        
        Label(self, text='Extra Seconds:',   
            bg='#252525', fg='#AAA4A6', font ="Gadugi 30 bold" ).place(x=170, y=240)
        Label(self, text='Extra Seconds are added every move.', 
            bg='#252525', fg='#656565', font ="Gadugi 15"      ).place(x=185, y=300)

        Label(self, text='Sound Notifications:', 
            bg='#252525', fg='#AAA4A6', font ="Gadugi 30 bold" ).place(x=170, y=380)
        Label(self, text='A sound notification will be emitted when clock is switched from a player to another one, when there is 30 or 10 seconds left ', 
            bg='#252525', fg='#656565', font ="Gadugi 11"      ).place(x=185, y=475)
        Label(self, text='and also when the game is over.', 
            bg='#252525', fg='#656565', font ="Gadugi 15"      ).place(x=185, y=500)


        self.setTime   = StringVar()
        self.entryTime = Entry(self, width=5, textvariable = self.setTime, 
            font="Gadugi 30", background='#252525', fg='white', justify='center', 
            insertbackground='white', borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.entryTime.place(x=1000, y=140)

        self.entryTime.focus()
        self.setTime.trace_add("write", callback1)

        self.onBtn  = Button(self, image=self.on,  bd=0, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, command=self.do_off)
        self.offBtn = Button(self, image=self.off, bd=0, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, command=self.do_on)
        self.offBtn.place(x=900, y=390)



root=root()
root.mainloop()
```